# How to get the class from a method in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, inspect

I am trying to write a function that gets the class when we pass a given method as argument.

For example, if we have

```py
class Hello:
    NAME = "HELLO TOTO"

    def method(self) -> int:
        return 5

    @classmethod
    def cls_method(cls) -> str:
        return "Hi"


class Bonjour(Hello):
    NOM = "BONJOUR TOTO"

    def new_method(self) -> int:
        return 0
```

I would get:

- `Hello` from the methods `Hello().method` or `Hello().cls_method`
- `Bonjour` from the methods `Bonjour().new_method` or `Bonjour().cls_method`

I searched on SO but could not find any direct answer to my question.

How could I implement such function (in Python 3.6+ if that matters)?

Thanks

Comment: What is your use-case for this? I'm wondering because the desired result is actually part of the argument. You are having `Hello` and `Bonjour` already.

Comment: Wait, hold on - you want a single solution to handle both classmethods and ordinary methods? **Why?** You would, AFAICT, be using the technique *to implement individual methods*, so you already know whether you are working within a classmethod or an ordinary method. Within the classmethod, the passed-in `cls` is already the class object you need; within the ordinary method, you can check `self.__class__`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, I want a single solution (although I actually only use ordinary methods). The question was not to get the class from the method itself, but rather passing this method to a function that would get the class.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's no fool-proof way, but this would work for most cases:

```
def get_class_of_bound_self(f):
    assert hasattr(f, '__self__')
    return f.__self__ if isinstance(f.__self__, type) else type(f.__self__)
```

Note that this would break down if `f` is a method of a metaclass `M`; it would return `M` instead of `type`.

Comment: thanks... I like your `isinstance(self, type)`~! :)  ... but what is this argument `self` actually?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. I simplified it. Is it clearer now? Or perhaps I do not understand you question.

Comment: It was clear before. Just a typo `if isinstance(self, type):` istead of `if isinstance(self_or_cls, type):`  [missing `_or_cls`]. And the question was well understood and was solving the problem (although I had actually a solution when posting the question :))

Answer (score 1):

I came with the following solution:

```py
import inspect

def get_class(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> Any:
    """Return class of a method.

    Args:
        func: callable

    Returns:
        Class of the method, if the argument is a method

    Raises:
        AttributeError: if the argument is not callable or not a method
    """
    if not callable(func):
        raise AttributeError(f"{func} shall be callable")
    if not inspect.ismethod(func):
        raise AttributeError(f"Callable {func} shall be a method")

    first_arg = func.__self__  # type: ignore  # method have "self" attribute
    return first_arg if inspect.isclass(first_arg) else first_arg.__class__
```

The last line `return first_arg if inspect.isclass(first_arg) else first_arg.__class__` is to handle the cases of class methods (in which case `func.__self__` corresponds to `cls` and is the class itself).

Another alternative without `inspect` module is with catching exceptions (a big thanks to @Elazar for the idea of using `isistance(..., type)`):

```py
def get_class(func: Callable[..., Any]) -> Any:
    """Return class of a method.

    Args:
        func: callable

    Returns:
        Class of the method, if the argument is a method

    Raises:
        AttributeError: if the argument is not callable or not a method
    """
    if not callable(func):
        raise AttributeError(f"{func} shall be callable")
    try:
        first_arg = func.__self__  # type: ignore  # method have "self" attribute
    except AttributeError:
        raise AttributeError(f"Callable {func} shall be a method")

    cls_or_type = first_arg.__class__
    return first_arg if isinstance(cls_or_type, type) else cls_or_type
```

And this is the code I have used to check if you might be interested:

```py
def my_func() -> int:
    """It feels like a zero"""
    return 0


for method in [
    Hello().method,
    Bonjour().method,
    Hello().cls_method,
    Bonjour().cls_method,
    Bonjour().new_method,
]:
    # MyClass = get_class(func)
    MyClass = get_class_2(method)
    for attr in ["NAME", "NOM"]:
        print(f"... {method} - {attr} ...")
        try:
            print(getattr(MyClass, attr))
        except AttributeError as exp:
            print(f"Error when getting attribute: {exp}")
# class_ = get_class(my_func)
for not_method in [my_func, int, Hello]:
    try:
        MyClass = get_class(not_method)
        print(f"{not_method} => NOK (no exception raised)")
    except AttributeError:
        print(f"{not_method} => OK")
```